# Finding sequences in rows in R based on the rep function on a certain column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to find a sequence of 0's in a row based on the rep function of a certain column. Below is my best attempt so far which throws an error. I tried using an apply loop but failed miserably and I don't really want to use a for loop unless I have to as my true dataset is about 800,000 rows. I have tried looking up solutions but can't seem to find anything and have spent a few hours at this and had no luck. I have also attached the desired output.

```
library(data.table)

TEST_DF <- data.table(INDEX = c(1,2,3,4),
                      COL_1 = c(0,0,0,0),
                      COL_2 = c(0,0,2,5),
                      COL_3 = c(0,0,0,0),
                      COL_4 = c(0,2,0,1),
                      DAYS  = c(4,4,2,2))

IN_FUN <- function(x, y)
{
  x <- rle(x)

  if( max(as.numeric(x$lengths[x$values == 0])) >= y )
  {
    "Y"
  }
  else
  {
    "N"
  }
}

TEST_DF$DEFINITION <- apply(TEST_DF[, c(2:5), with = FALSE], 1, 
                            FUN = IN_FUN(TEST_DF[, c(2:5), with = FALSE], TEST_DF$DAYS))

DESIRED <- TEST_DF <- data.table(P_ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                                 COL_1 = c(0,0,0,0),
                                 COL_2 = c(0,0,2,5),
                                 COL_3 = c(0,0,0,0),
                                 COL_4 = c(0,2,0,1),
                                 DAYS  = c(4,4,2,2).
                                 DEFINITION = c("Y","N","Y","N"),
                                 INDEX = c(2,NA,4,NA)
```

For the first row I want to see if four 0's are within COL_1 to COL_4, four 0's within row 2 and two 0's within rows 3 and 4. Basically the number of 0's is given by the value in the DAYS column. So since four 0's are within row 1, DEFINITION gets a value of "Y", row 2 gets a value of "N" since there is only three 0's row 4 should get a value of "Y" since there are two 0's, etc.

Also, if possible, if the DEFINITION column has a value of "Y" in it, then it should return the column index of the first occurrence of the desired sequence, e.g. in row 1 since the first occurrence of a 0 in the 4 0's we're looking for is in COL_1 then we should get a value of 2 for the INDEX column and row 2 get a NA since DEFINITION is "N", etc.

Feel free to make any edits to make it clearer for other users and let me know if you need better information.

Cheers in advance :)

**EDIT:**
Below is a slightly extended data table. Let me know if this is sufficient.

```
TEST_DF <- data.table(P_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10),
                  COL_1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,90),
                  COL_2 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,3,78,6),
                  COL_3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0),
                  COL_4 = c(0,0,0,0,0,5,0,2,0),
                  COL_5 = c(0,0,0,0,0,7,2,0,0),
                  COL_6 = c(0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,5),
                  COL_7 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,6),
                  COL_8 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,8),
                  COL_9 = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,6,1,0),
                  COL_10 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,0),
                  COL_11 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,8,3,0),
                  COL_12 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,9,6,7),
                  DAYS = c(10,8,12,4,5,4,3,4,7))
```

Where the DEFINITION column for the rows would be c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0) where 1 is "Y" and 0 is "N". Either is ok.

For the INDEX column in the new edit the values should be c(2,2,2,2,2,NA,7,NA,NA)

Comment: In your edit, why would the 7th row DEFINITION value by 1 and not zero?  There are non-zero values in it.  And what should the ```INDEX``` values be for this new data?

Comment: And the ```DAYS``` column doesn't seem to correspond to the number of zeros found in each row.

Comment: Think a slight misunderstanding due to my poor explanation. The DAYS column isn't a result of COL_1 to COL_12. What the DAYS column says is look for a sequence rep(0, DAYS[i]) in each row between COL_1 and COL_12. Looking at row 1 we want to see are there 10 0's within COL_1 to COL_12. For row 7, we want to see are there 3 consecutive 0's between COL_1 and COL_12 and there is between COL_6 and COL_8. Lastly for let's say row 9 we 're looking for 9 consecutive 0's for which there is no such occurrence between COL_1 and COL_12 so DEFINITION gets a 0 or "N" here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong(and little to no time penalty) in writing a clean `for` loop vs. `apply` . Write what's easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do this with some math trickery.  I created a binary matrix where an element is 1 if it was originally 0 and 0 otherwise.  Then, for each row I set the nth element in the row equal to the (n-1th element + the nth element) times the nth element.  In this transformed matrix, the value of an element is equal to the number of consecutive prior elements which were 0 (including this element).

```
m<-as.matrix(TEST_DF[, 2:(ncol(TEST_DF)-1L)])
m[m==1]<-2
m[m==0]<-1
m[m!=1]<-0

for(i in 2:ncol(m)){
  m[,i]=(m[,i-1]+m[,i])*m[,i]
}

# note the use of with=FALSE -- this forces ncol to be evaluated
#   outside of TEST_DF, leading the result to be used as a
#   column number instead of just evaluating to a scalar
m<-as.matrix(cbind(m, Days=TEST_DF[,ncol(TEST_DF),with=FALSE]))
indx<-apply(m[,-ncol(m)] >= m[,ncol(m)],1,function(x) match(TRUE,x) )

TEST_DF$DEFINITION<-ifelse(is.na(indx),0,1)
TEST_DF$INDEX<-indx-TEST_DF$DAYS+2
```

Note: I stole some stuff from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987548/r-get-the-column-index-of-a-matrix-based-on-a-function-for-each-row/24987640#24987640)

Comment: Thanks Ben. Had to tweak it slightly because for whatever reason the line m[m==1]<-2 didn't in result in my matrix in my original data being binarised. Still though, I like your solution and it was the first one to work, also easy to run and understand so the green tick goes to you. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand this better now that the question has been edited some. This has loops so it might not be optimal speed-wise, but the set statement should help with this. It still has some of the speed-up that data.table provides.

```
#Combined all column values in giant string
TEST_DF[ , COL_STRING := paste(COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6,COL_7,COL_8,COL_9,COL_10,COL_11,COL_12,sep=",")]
TEST_DF[ , COL_STRING := paste0(COL_STRING,",")]

#Using the Days variable, create a string to be searched
for (i in 1:nrow(TEST_DF))
  set(TEST_DF,i=i,j="FIND",value=paste(rep("0,",TEST_DF[i]$DAYS),sep="",collapse=""))

#Find where pattern starts. A negative 1 value means it does not exist
for (i in 1:nrow(TEST_DF))
  set(TEST_DF,i=i,j="INDEX",value=regexpr(TEST_DF[i]$FIND,TEST_DF[i]$COL_STRING,fixed=TRUE)[1])

#Define DEFINITION
TEST_DF[ , DEFINITION := 1*(INDEX != -1)]

#Find where pattern starts. A negative 1 value means it does not exist
require(stringr)
for (i in 1:nrow(TEST_DF))
  set(TEST_DF,i=i,j="INDEX",value=str_count(substr(TEST_DF[i]$COL_STRING,1,TEST_DF[i]$INDEX),","))

#Clean up variables
TEST_DF[ , INDEX := INDEX + DEFINITION*2L]
TEST_DF[INDEX==0L, INDEX := NA_integer_]
```

Comment: Thanks you Mike for all your effort and for your solution. I'm sure your solution will be of interest to other users as it was of use to me in my learning of R. I liked the simplicity of Ben's solution so I gave him the green tick although your efforts merit a green tick as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might explore the IRanges package. I just defined the test dataset as a `data.frame`, since I am not familiar with `data.table`. I then expanded it to your dataset size of 800000:

```
TEST_DF <- TEST_DF[sample(nrow(TEST_DF), 800000, replace=TRUE),]
```

Then, we put IRanges to work:

```
library(IRanges)
m <- t(as.matrix(TEST_DF[,2:13]))
l <- relist(Rle(m), PartitioningByWidth(rep(nrow(m), ncol(m))))
r <- ranges(l)
validRuns <- width(r) >= TEST_DF$DAYS
TEST_DF$DEFINITION <- sum(validRuns) > 0
TEST_DF$INDEX <- drop(phead(start(r)[validRuns], 1)) + 1L
```

The first step simplifies the table to a matrix, so we can transpose and get things in the right layout for a light-weight partitioning (`PartitioningByWidth`) of the data into a type of list. The data are converted into a run-length encoding (`Rle`) along the way, which finds the runs of zeros in each row. We can extract the `ranges` representing the runs and then compute on them more efficiently than we might on the split `Rle` directly. We find the runs that meet or exceed the `DAYS` and record which groups (rows) have at least one such run. Finally, we find the `start` of the valid runs, take the first start for each group with `phead`, and `drop` so that those with no runs become `NA`.

For 800,000 rows, this takes about 4 seconds. If that's not fast enough, we can work on optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Michael. Ben was first in with a correct solution so I gave him the green tick. I appreciate your effort in giving any interested users a different solution but I can only give 1 green tick I'm afraid. I will mention though that I had trouble downloading the IRanges package the conventional install.packages way so I googled it and the following lines install the package for any interested other users: source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R");biocLite("IRanges")