# R - get the column index of a matrix based on a function for each row

Tags: r, matrix

```
> set.seed(2014)
> m<-matrix(sample(10,16,replace=TRUE),nrow=4)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6    1    7
[2,]    2    1    2    6
[3,]    7   10    7    7
[4,]    4    7    1    5
```

For each row, I'd like to retrieve the index of the first element in that row which is greater than or equal to the last element, and NA otherwise.  So, for row 1, there are no elements>=7 in the first three columns, so NA should be returned.  For row 3, the first element is >=7 so 1 should be returned.

The result should be a vector of length 4 equal to (NA, NA, 1, 2)

I thought the solution might involve apply but I couldn't figure out how to get it right.  Also, please keep efficiency in mind as my real matrix could have millions of rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another attempt:

```
apply(m[,-ncol(m)] >= m[,ncol(m)], 1, match, x=TRUE)
#[1] NA NA  1  2
```

Or removing `apply`:

```
chk <- m[,-ncol(m)] >= m[,ncol(m)]
replace(max.col(chk,"first"), rowSums(chk)==0, NA)
#[1] NA NA  1  2
```

It essentially creates a logical matrix of the all the `m` columns except the last, testing if the values are `>=` to the last column values. Then the position of the first `TRUE` in each row is extracted using `match`.

Testing speed using a bigger matrix against Ben's solution:

```
m<-matrix(sample(10,1.6e6,replace=TRUE),nrow=4e5)

replicate(5,
system.time(
 apply(m[,-ncol(m)] >= m[,ncol(m)], 1, match, x=TRUE)
))
#elapsed     0.7 0.77 0.77 0.76 0.93

replicate(5,
system.time({
 m2 <- sweep(m,1,m[,ncol(m)],">=")
 v <- apply(m2,1,function(x) which(x)[1])
 ifelse(v==ncol(m),NA,v)
}))
#elapsed    1.11 1.04 1.10 1.06 1.06
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility -- it might use a lot of space for interim results though.

```
set.seed(2014)
m <- matrix(sample(10,16,replace=TRUE),nrow=4)
m2 <- sweep(m,1,m[,ncol(m)],">=")
v <- apply(m2,1,function(x) which(x)[1])
ifelse(v==ncol(m),NA,v)
```

An Rcpp-based solution that iterated through each row only as far as it needed to would be faster (it would be nice if someone had written a generic, fast `which.first()` function ...

Comment: I second the need for a `which.first` - it shouldn't be that hard to write surely? (Says me with no C programming experience).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
getFirst <- function(vec) {
  temp = which(vec[1:(length(vec)-1)] >= vec[length(vec)])  
  if(length(temp) == 0) NA else temp[1]
}

index <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  index[i] <- getFirst(m[i,])
}
index
```

You can do this in one step as well:

```
apply(m,1,function(vec) {
  temp = which(vec[1:(length(vec)-1)] >= vec[length(vec)])  
  if(length(temp) == 0) NA else temp[1]
})
```